# automatically managing Java objects

Tags: java, object

I'm still a little new to Java, and I'm quite confused with how objects are supposed to be used. I know of

```
object object = new object();
```

but these have to be accessed manually.

say I wanted to create a particle effect. small white dots appear in the centere of the screen, and slowly move to an edge of the screen at a random angle. as they approach, they go faster. finally, they are removed if they go out of the view area.

if I wanted to do this with objects, I would need to be able to:

- automatically make objects
- collect data from every object (their X and Y co-ordinates)
  so that they can be rendered
- have the objects update every frame so that they can increase speed
- destroy the objects when they go out of bounds.

How would I automatically make/destroy objects, and take in data from all of them independent of how many objects are present?
Right now, my games (well, I've only ever made 1 in Java) are limited to using an array and a sort of cellular automata, but this won't work for bigger games.

This might have been asked before or there might be a tutorial on this, but all I managed to find was manually making objects. I'm probably searching for the wrong thing, so sorry if this is the case.

Comment: I would use a collection of objects which represent your `Partitle`. This could use an array in reality but I would worry about what you need the program to do rather than how it does it at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating Objects

I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically create objects", but this is what constructors are for.  When you define a constructor, you can add all sorts of implementation and initialization details in there that will create your variable exactly how you want it to be created.  See ["Providing Constructors for your classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).  So say you have a point...

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    this.color = Color.BLUE;
    this.size = Constants.DEFAULT_POINT_SIZE;
    // ... etc.
}
```

### Collecting Data from Objects

Getting and setting information in these classes would be achieved through getters and setters (also known as [accessors and mutators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)).

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.xPos = x;
}
```

To collect the data from all objects in existence, independently of how many there are, simply have them all added to a `List` of some kind.  You could even add them to a `private static ArrayList<T>` in your constructor and access the `ArrayList<T>` statically for your information without another part of your program ever having to "know" how many there are.

### Incremental GUI Changes

There are a couple ways to implement your frame-by-frame changes, but I prefer using a `Timer` and an `ActionListener`.  This allows you to set your frame rate and, in the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method to perform the actions you require.  This is somewhat complicated for a beginner, so you will likely have to do a good bit of reading and testing.  See ["How to Write an Action Listener"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and ["How to Use Swing Timers"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to get you started.

### Destroying Objects

There are no destructors in Java as there are in languages like C++.  Instead, there is a [*garbage collector*](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) which runs periodically (and sporadically) which destroys all objects it deems no longer have a reference pointing to them.  Thus, if you want the garbage collector to pick up your objects when they go out of bounds, simply assign all references to them to **null**.  While this won't destroy the object immediately, it ensures that they will be "tagged" by the garbage collector on its next run through.

As mentioned, `System.gc()` is a method to "invoke" the garbage collector.  However, you should not assume that calling it will *force* the garbage collector to run.  In the API, it says that this call "suggests" to the System that it should run the garbage collector.  Ultimately, it is not reliable and garbage collection is generally outside of your scope of control.

From [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29):

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Also, as a side nit pick, be sure to capitalize the class name when you are creating objects. :)

```
Object object = new Object();
```

---

**For OP's specific purposes:** If you are concerned about a game environment where you are "drawing everything that exists," (and so you want to destroy the objects *immediately* to ensure that the game runs correctly), consider using a `List` or `Set` and populating that with the things you want to draw, then removing them as they go off the screen.

---

**References:**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.htm
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I'm still a little new to Java so I barely understood what you said there, but I will certainly visit the tutorial links. thanks!

Comment: If you need clarification on anything, let me know and I'll update the post. :)  The project you seem to be working on is a little advanced for a beginner, but constructors, getters/setters, and lists are definitely where I'd start reading.  The actual GUI and "frame-by-frame changes" are very advanced and will be implemented with Swing.

Answer (score 2):

In java you do not destroy objects. There is garbage collector, which destroy objects which are not used. It is enough to assign null value to the variable holding the object.

You can invoke manually garbage collector by System.gc() .

Comment: +1 remember to mention that references that go out of scope also delete their not-accesible-anymore referenced objects. And about creating objects... you'll need a timer, or something executing every little time to create new objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I would need to have some code to automatically make objects before I can worry about deleting them. like objects/NPCs in a game sort of system. it must be possible somehow...

Answer (score 0):

> automatically make objects

**Answer:** You will always need `new` `newInstance` to create objects in java. This will be based on algorithm. Just to give example. You can have a two-dimensional array  to hold objects and based on X,Y position you can put object in that array and use Random class to generate X, Y positions.

e.g.

```
    //Initialize pallete
    Point [][] pallete = Point int [800][600];
    //Generate Objects

    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(800);
    int y = random. nextInt(600);

    Point point = new Point(x,y);

    //Put inside Pallete

    pallete[point.x][point.y] = point;
```

> collect data from every object (their X and Y co-ordinates) so that they can be rendered

**Answer:** As shown above declare properties to objects that you want like I have declared for Point [x, y]

> have the objects update every frame so that they can increase speed

**Answer:** Increase speed of generation using loop or Timer etc.

> destroy the objects when they go out of bounds.

**Answer:** Just initialize it to null and it will be get GC'ed. If you face OutOfMemory Issue then there are several ways to solve it but you should not focus on that unless there is need.

```
 point = null;//This is it.
```